# Why is Command.ExecuteNonQuery giving me a compilation error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I receive the following error:

> ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or UserControl).

The code in my aspx.vb file is this. Can someone please tell me what I am missing in my file?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Public Class NewMeetings
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal a As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=c3digpssql2;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ServiceLine_Committee")
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) , " +
                                       "SELECT C.ID, M.ID, CM.FULL_NAME FROM ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeName C, " +
                                       "ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblMeetings M, ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeMembers CM, " +
                                       "WHERE (M.ContractCategory   = C.Contract_Category, " +
                                       "AND M.Committee         = C.Committee_Name, " +
                                       "AND CM.Committee            = M.Committee)", con)

            Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: what line gives you the error?

Comment: Get rid of those commas in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Considering the error message, it's probably a good idea to show your `@ Page` declaration from the .aspx. Try to anticipate these obvious things when you ask a question - it'll save some needless back and forth.